# Exploring the files in a MobileSync backup

Tags: iphone, backup

I'm trying to find if some movies that I had on my iPhone 5 might be hidden away in a MobileSync backup.  The weird part is that iTunes → Preferences → Devices doesn't show a backup for this device in February, but there's a folder in the MobileSync backup folder that shows a Feb 10, 2013 last modified date.

What I'd like to do is find out what all is in that folder without having to restore a device. Honestly, I'm not sure how to do the restore anyway, since there's no entry in iTunes for it.

Is there any way to browse what is in each backup?

Comment: did you end finding out how to view the mobile sync files?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the DIY method:

Navigate to the following directory:

~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/

You'll get a cryptic list of folders.  Inside each folder will be a large number of files with cryptic names.

Open these files in Quicktime Player.

There may be thousands of them but if you sort by size you should get video, audio and photos to float to the top.

Alternatively you could try one of the applications that is meant to do this such as [iPhone Backup Extractor](http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/) (There is a free and a paid version I have not tried either myself).

Comment: are you now aware of any way to do this without special software or are you aware of any freeware programs to view these files that arent malware/spyware/etc?? thanks

Comment: im wanting to import some text message histories and view them on the PC, but i also dont wanna drop $30-40 on sketchy looking software if possible.

Answer (score 1):

### [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)

iExplorer will let you browse iTunes backups.

1. Open iExplorer and click the **Browse iTunes Backups** button.

   [image]
2. Your most recent backup should be shown. It should show multiple 'domains' as below:

   [image]
3. The data you are looking for should be in the **MediaDomain**.

   [image]

Comment: are you now aware of any way to do this without special software or are you aware of any freeware programs to view these files that youre sure arent or dont have malware/spyware/etc associated with it?? thanks

Comment: im wanting to import some text message histories and view them on the PC, but i also dont wanna drop $30-40 on sketchy looking software if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users, these are just raw media files without extensions. `mpv` will play them. Not the most efficient way to view them, but it is an option.